# I can't get this seemingly simple insert query to work

Tags: sql, postgresql

guys. I have a query that is meant to take a result from one table and insert it into another table. It looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted 
    SELECT * FROM minutes
    WHERE minutes_id = 103
```

Now, I didn't even know you could try and insert like that. (I thought insert statements all had the syntax, `INSERT INTO blah VALUES (some values)`, but after reading the manual I figured out you can.

Now, the issue is that this gives an error: `column "meeting_id" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying` I believe this error happens because the columns in `minutes_deleted` are in a different order than the ones in `minutes_id`.

`minutes_deleted` also has some columns that are not found in `minutes`, but all columns in `minutes` can be found in `minutes_deleted`, though in a jumbled order.

According to the manual, all of the columns of the table that has stuff stuffed in(i.e. `minutes_deleted` must be given a value, if I could get past the column order, the query would probably still fail because of that.

So, two quick questions if you will:

1)-How do I go about rearranging the order of the columns, so it works.
2)-How do I specify an empty value for the columns in `minutes_deleted` that do not exist in `minutes`?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: **wouldn't it have been faster to just list out the columns of each table?**  seems like entering a question on SO just to figure this out is a waste of time.  it is best practice to always enter the columns of an `insert` and never `select *`.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that your destination and source tables don't have the same column datatypes in the same order.

To fix this, be explicit in your column order for both your destination and source.

```
 INSERT INTO MyDestination ( Column1, Column2, Column3)
      SELECT ColumnA,
             ColumnB,
             ColumnC
      FROM   MySource;
```

- ColumnA must be same type as Column1
- ColumnB must be same type as Column2
- ColumnC must be same type as Column3

Employ casting/converting as you need to fit the destination.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, but uhmm, what's the syntax to do that? Do, I just go `SELECT column1, column3, column2 ... FROM..`

Comment: +1 It is a poor practice to ever do an insert without explicitly specifying the columns.

Comment: if the datatypes are differnt you may need to specifically cast them to the correct datatype inthe selct part of the statement. If they won't cast, then you have a data issue where the data in the source table won't work with the datatype in the destination table and you need to find and fix those bad pieces of data.

Comment: This is good, definitely specify the columns.  To answer the second part of your question, you have a couple of options.  First, you can select nulls for the columns that don't exist in minutes_deleted (something like INSERT INTO minutes_deleted (columnA, columnB, columnCnotinminutes) SELECT columnA, columnB, NULL FROM minutes).  Alternately, you can specify default constraints on the columns in minutes_deleted that don't exist in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I do this kind of insert, I generally have to specifically list out the columns unless they're perfect matches:

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted (somecol1, somecol2, somecol3)
    SELECT somecol1, somecol2, somecol3
    FROM minutes
    WHERE minutes_id = 103
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use that syntax, minutes and minutes_deleted have to have the same number of columns, of the same type, in the same order. You're better off being more explicit by listing the columns. It won't prevent the error you're seeing, but it will make it more obvious.

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted 
    (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
    SELECT AnotherCol1, AnotherCol2, ..., AnotherColN 
        FROM minutes
        WHERE minutes_id = 103
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted(value1)
SELECT theValueToInsert FROM minutes
WHERE minutes_id = 103
```

Do not use *.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe Enos, but with ability to set some columns to data not in second table:

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted (somecol1, somecol2, somecol3)
SELECT somecol1, somecol2, "static text" as somecol3
FROM minutes
WHERE minutes_id = 103
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question 2)

```
INSERT INTO minutes_deleted (col_1, col_2,col_3, col_5) -- note the missing col4
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_e  -- note the missing col_d
  FROM minutes
 WHERE minutes_id = 103;
```

You can explicitly set the column to `NULL`, but there is a simpler way on `INSERT`:
**Omit** the field in the INSERT statement (as shown above) and it will be set to its default, which is `NULL` as long as you have not defined it otherwise.

To be precise, if the column in question is a string type (like `text`) the closest thing to an "empty value" would be an empty string rather than `NULL`. For that you would INSERT `''` - two single quotes with nothing in between.